# Calling open() method in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

While using the method `open()`, I realized that it takes a `URL` file as argument.

For example, I have `generateGeometricShapes()` and `colorShapes()` as two functions. I was wondering should I create a separate files for every function in order to call `open()` correctly?

And what if I have `n` calls for the `open()` method? should I be creating `n` files of functions? Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: you could use jquery

Comment: @Andrew What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: It's really up to you. If you want to keep your project small and compact, put everything in one JS file. It's always better to try and re-use your methods rather than duplicating them.

Comment: @Mikey nothing, that's why suggesting jquery

Comment: what is your server language?

Comment: @Andrew, I'm using PHP as server language

Answer (score -2):

Super broad question but anyways, you don't need to have a different file for every ajax call. You might `GET` or `POST` a parameter that you use to direct to the right method (for example "action"). Then in your file (you could call it a **router** or **controller**), you just route to the needed function for example:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'generateGeometricShapes'){
    generateGeometricShapes();
}
```